# Get Ubuntu Anywhere?

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop, cloud, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up remote desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7446/how-do-i-set-up-remote-desktop)

I want to be able to remote to my Ubuntu desktop from anywhere, but securely. Windows, of course, has all kinds of free programs that I can use, such as logmein.com & pocket cloud.
What is the best, most secure way to do this for my Ubuntu desktop & how can I do it without needing a static IP address?

Comment: To my understanding, I can set up SSH on my desktop, but I thought that this would mean I would need a static IP address for my router in order to accomplish my desires. Not sure if that's true or not. I have a free account @ dyndns but I'm not sure if it keeps up with new IP address leases that my router may recieve. Also, information on setting up SSH keys is a little confusing for me on the Ubuntu wiki & some other reference sites, any good suggestions will be voted up by me of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the free program teamviewer, http://www.teamviewer.com/, it doesn't need a static ip, you can access your computer from your browser and the connection is encrypted. If you use compiz effects you do have to turn them off, because else you won't be able to do anything.

Comment: Perfect! I tried this and it's exactly what I want. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

X2go is a nice terminal server and easily installed. It works over ssh and if you don't want to use a static IP, then you'll need to get yourself a DynDNS solution, from dyndns.org, for example. Or you can get an Ubuntu server on any VPS host if you're willing to spend a few coins.

Comment: X2go is only TUI, it seems

Comment: TUI? You get your desktop over the network.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of options, my favourite is [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/). Also Google Chrome has a new extension for remote desktop control called **Chrome Remote Desktop**. It's in beta right now, but still, [this is article about it is at Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/google-releases-cross-platform-remote.html)

Answer (score 2):

I read an interesting article about that today. It's still in beta, but Google is developing something like that for all platforms. It's a Chrome extension but it still allows you to control the whole desktop.

Article: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/google-releases-cross-platform-remote.html
Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp