# What is the alternative for Teamviewer?

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop, teamviewer

Is there any Ubuntu alternative for team-viewer software for Windows?

Comment: and this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/7446/how-do-i-set-up-remote-desktop

Comment: Yeah Teamviewer Works,JusT Checked

Comment: you can also use webbased software like logmein

Comment: You could use Remmina (it may need some improvements to become as simple to use as TV), see: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/43686/32856

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Teamviewer it-self](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/).

Otherwise, there is Open-source alternative. Look at some client for [RDP](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/06/connect-to-ubuntu-11-04-from-windows-via-remote-desktop/) protocol, or [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC) protocol.

Comment: Doesn't work on Debian 8.3 (dependency hell)...

Answer (score 4):

Teamviewer works on Ubuntu too. download for the [32 bit version](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb) or the [64 bit version](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb). So if you like that as remote desktop software you can still use it ;)

But if you really want an alternative I suggest to take a look at [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC). But the server side as the client side are easy to get working.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try VNC as mentioned above or [ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can install team viewer in Ubuntu too, i have **Ubuntu 14.04** and running **Teamviewer** without wine......

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

The official TeamViewer port for Ubuntu is a Wine wrapped program. It works as expected though, so you should try that!