# RunninG Teamviewer Or Same Kinda Program On Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the alternative for Teamviewer on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119650/what-is-the-alternative-for-teamviewer-on-ubuntu)

I Have One More Question. Is There Teamviewer Available On Linux? Or Maybe there is Another programme Called Just otherway? Or the only way to Run TW is By Wine? 10x anyway -_-

Answer (score 0):

There is TeamViewer, downloadable here: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx

Comment: Oh I Didn't Check The Off site,So stupid .. 10x Bro

Answer (score 0):

Team viewer is available for ubuntu and other linux distros.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx

Comment: Oh I Didn't Check The Off site,So stupid .. 10x Bro